# ASP.NET DropdownList populated from MYSQL always returns first value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have strange issue going on: Whatever I'm choosing from my DropDownList populated from MySQL database it always returns the value of first item in it.

Here's HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="selectStudentList"/>
```

and C#:

```
String getStudentsQuery = "SELECT CONCAT(imie,' ',nazwisko) AS name, id FROM users WHERE klasa = " + Session["rok"] + " AND access = 0";
        cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(getStudentsQuery, conn);

        var students = new DataTable();
        students.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        selectStudentList.DataSource = students;
        selectStudentList.DataTextField = "name";
        selectStudentList.DataValueField = "id";
        selectStudentList.DataBind();
```

I've checked if fields are populated corectly. When I'm choosing lets say second item from dropdown and sending it via form the value: `selectStudentList.SelectedValue` always returns id of first item, even if another is chosen

Any tips? :)

Comment: Have you tried adding an "empty item", something like "-- Select a value --"?

Comment: first please check datatable is values is coming properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're loading that dropdownlist in the page load and aren't checking for a post back it would do that. I.e. since you're loading it on page load every time, it gets reloaded.

Try throwing the c# code in an if(!ispostback){//loadHere}

Comment: Yea, don't forget about the if not postback. You'll probably end up using it in about any page you build that's in webforms. And it can make you go crazy if you're on a big page and just realize your issue was simply that something needed moved into that.